# Why would an interactive git rebase have conflicts if nothing changed?

Tags: git

Here's my scenario. I need to change an old commit message that got pushed to remote. I'm OK force pushing since I'm the only one working on the branch right now.

So I do the usual `git rebase -i HEAD~5`, select the commit I want to change with `r`, save and continue. Git does its rebase thing but when it gets to about (5/12) it stops because it found conflicts in several files, leaving me scratching my head and running the proverbial `git rebase --abort`

It's not just a one-off either. If I do `git rebase --skip` there are several more conflicts after.

I'm actually just trying to understand why there would be conflicts when nothing changed. Working tree clean and up to date with remote.

Edit: The conflicts that happen appear to ones I fixed a few days ago when merging in other branches. But it's just that, they were already fixed.

Comment: Have you tried `rerere`?  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I do the usual git rebase -i HEAD~5 ...

OK, so we have at least:

```
...--o--*--A--B--C--D--E   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

where `branch` identifies commit `E` and you're going to copy `A`-through-`E` to new-and-improved commits.  After making the five copies, you will have:

```
          A'-B'-C'-D'-E'  <-- branch (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*--A--B--C--D--E   [abandoned originals]
```

which we can re-draw as:

```
...--o--*--A'-B'-C'-D'-E'  <-- branch (HEAD)
         \
          A--B--C--D--E   [abandoned originals]
```

(which is probably more comfortable, but is really the same drawing).  The commits marked with the prime-tick-marks `'` are the shiny new copies that are somehow better than the originals (e.g., have their commit messages changed, or—for later commits—use the ID of the shiny new parent instead of the dull old parent).

> ... but when [Git] gets to about (5/12) ...

Whoa, where did the other seven commits to copy come from?

Seriously, think about that question: *Where did the other seven, of the twelve commits you've asked Git to copy, come from?*

#### The above graph is necessarily wrong

The graph we drew above, that had five commits to copy, has five commits "after" (not-reachable-from) commit `*`.  Commit `*` is the commit that is five first-parent steps back from commit `E`, i.e., is `HEAD~5`.  *This part is necessarily correct:* commit `*` really *is* five first-parent steps back from commit `E`, as `HEAD~5` *means* "traverse five first-parent links backwards from `HEAD`" and `HEAD` identifies commit `E` (that's why we called it commit `E` here).

So the graph *must* look different.  One reasonably likely possibility is this:

```
...o------o--*--A--B--C--D--E   <-- branch (HEAD)
    \                      /
     F--G--H--I--J--K--L--M
```

Now there are *13* commits that are reachable from the name `branch` (the branch name to which `HEAD` is attached), that are *not* reachable from commit `*`.  One of these is a merge—I've chosen `E` here, but any of `A` through `E` could be the merge, or there could be more than one merge.

Your `git rebase` will (try to) copy all of the non-merge commits to shiny new commits, placing all *twelve* after commit `*`:

```
               F'-G'-H'-I'-J'-K'-L'-M'-A'-B'-C'-D'   <-- branch (HEAD)
              /
...o------o--*--A--B--C--D--E   [abandoned]
    \                      /
     F--G--H--I--J--K--L--M
```

or:

```
               A'-B'-C'-D'-F'-G'-H'-I'-J'-K'-L'-M'   <-- branch (HEAD)
              /
...o------o--*--A--B--C--D--E   [abandoned]
    \                      /
     F--G--H--I--J--K--L--M
```

(the actual order is a bit difficult to predict—it's whatever comes out of `git rev-list` given the options that `git rebase -i` passes).

Note that a side effect of rebase is to *discard* merges, replacing them with an attempt to linearize the new commits.  It's this linearization and discarding-of-merges that is leading to the merge conflict you see.

#### What to do about it

That depends.  The first thing to do is to discover the true shape of the graph.  The one I drew above is just a guess; there could be some other shape.

Suppose the actual shape looks more like this:

```
     ...--o--o
              \
...--o--o--o---o--X--o   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

and the commit I marked `X` is the one that has a commit-message typo that you'd like to fix.  *This commit is not followed by any merges*, so you can fix it a lot more easily: just select the commit before it, `HEAD~3` in this case, as the base for your `git rebase -i`.

If the commit whose message you want to fix comes earlier, consider using `git rebase -i -p`, which will *reconstruct* the merge.  You may have to resolve merge conflicts.  Be careful: combining `-i` with `-p` is tricky.  Consider not doing this at all.

You can also use `git replace` followed by `git filter-branch`.  This is even more tricky, but in some ways, less dangerous than combining interactive rebase with `-p`.

Last, although this is a repeat, consider not doing this at all.  It's deliberately hard—well, impossible, to a first approximation—to change things in existing commits.  You should have a very good reason for this recopying of commits.

Comment: OP: the shape of your graph is relevant information. If you don't _know_ it, you should find out what it looks like before performing surgery on it. If you do know it, that information should have been in your question.

Comment: This is enormously helpful in understanding how rebases work with merges. Thank you!